# Characterisation of Pronormal subgroups of finite solvable groups by its system normalizers

Tags: group-theory

**Definition**: A subgroup $H$ of $G$ is said to be pronormal if for all $g\in G$, there exists $x\in \langle H, H^g \rangle$ such that $H^g = H^x$

**Definition**: Let $\Sigma$ be a Hall system of $G$. Then is system normalizer of $G$ is of the form $ N_G(\Sigma) = \{ g\in G \,|\, H=H^g \;\text{ for all  } H \in \Sigma \}$

**Lemma**: Let $G$ be a finite solvable group. Suppose that $H \leq G$ is pronormal in every proper subgroup of $G$ in which it is contained. Then $H$ is pronormal in $G$ $\iff$  $N_G(H)$ contains some system normalizer of $G$

---

> **Theorem**: [Wood] Let $G$ be finite solvable group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $H$ is pronormal in $G$;
>
> (b) Whenever $H \leq L \leq G$, then $N_L(H)$ contains some system normalizer of $L$.

I have already shown (a) $\implies$ (b)

For (b) $\implies$ (a) Proceed by induction on $|G|$. (This allows to assume that $H$ is pronormal in every proper subgroup in which it is contained to use the Lemma). I'm not sure what should I do next to use the induction hypothesis. Do I use an arbitrary subgroup $L$ of $G$ such that $H \leq L \leq G$? or should I use a specific subgroup, say $L = \langle H, D \rangle$, where $D$ is some system normalizer of $G$, and then use the hypothesis of (b)?

Comment: I am confused. You seem to have assumed in (b) that $N_G(H)$ contains a system normalizer of $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I want use induction on $|G|$ to show (b) $\implies (a)$. I think the Lemma will be useful, but I'm not sure how to argue this.

Comment: I suggest you use  induction on $[G:H]$. It is certainly true for $[G:H]=1$, and the lemma will provide the inductive step.

Comment: @DerekHolt, For $[G : H] =1$, we have $G =H$ and the result is true. For $[G:H] > 1$, we have that $H < G$. Why can we assume for the induction hypothesis that $H$ is pronormal in every proper subgroup of $G$ in which it is contained? (I have not done induction on the index of a subgroup before)

Comment: Because the index of $H$ in any proper subgroup of $G$ is smaller than its index in $G$, so we can apply the induction hypothesis to it.

Comment: Okay, assume that $H < G$ and $H$ pronormal in every proper subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. Now let $M$ be the maximal subgroup of $G$ containing $H$. By (b) we have for some system normalizer $D_M$ of $M$, $D_M \leq N_M(H)$. Also by induction, $H$ is pronormal in $M$. (I want to use the result given by Phillip Hall that for a non-normal maximal subgroup $M$ of a finite solvable group $G$, every system normalizer of $M$ contains some system normalizer of $G$) So I need to show that $M$ is not normal in $G$. I'm not sure how to go about this. Also will $D_M$ be a system normalizer of $G$?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not understanding your problem. You are assuming by (b) that $N_G(H)$ contains some system normalizer of $G$, and now it follows directly from the lemma that $H$ is pronormal in $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Condition (b) is that whenever $H \leq L \leq G$, we have some system normalizer of $L$ is contained in $N_L(H)$. For the case I have $H \leq M < G$, so that for some system normalizer $D_M \leq N_M(H) \leq N_G(H)$. Is this not the correct way? I can't say anything about $N_G(H)$ containing a system normalizer of $G$ as yet

Comment: So putting $L=G$ in your first sentence, we have that some system normalizer of $G$ is contained in $N_G(H)$.